# Rate of divergence of improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, asymptotics, improper-integrals

Let $f:[0,1)\to(0,\infty)$ be a smooth function whose improper integral diverges. In other words, if $I_1(x)=\int_0^x f(t)\,dt$ for $0\leq x<1$, we have $\lim_{x\nearrow1}I_1(x)=\infty$. Then the improper integral of the square of $f$ also diverges, i.e. if $I_2(x)=\int_0^x f(t)^2\,dt$, then $\lim_{x\nearrow1}I_2(x)=\infty$. To see this, simply note that $$I_2(x)\geq I_2(x)\cdot x=I_2(x)\cdot\int_0^xdt\geq I_1(x)^2\to\infty,$$ where we used Hölder's inequality for the last inequality. The inequality above also tells us more: it tells us that $I_2$ diverges at least as fast as $I_1$ squared, i.e. that $I_1(x)^2=O(I_2(x))$ as $x\nearrow 1$. Is it true that $I_1(x)^2=o(I_2(x))$, or is there a counterexample where $I_1(x)^2$ and $I_2(x)$ diverge at the same rate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We always have $I_1(x)^2 = o(I_2(x))$. Choose $y \in [0,1)$ arbitrarily. Then for $y < x < 1$ we have by the Cauchy-Schwarz or Hölder inequality
$$\Biggl(\int_y^x f(t)\,dt\Biggr)^2 \leqslant (x-y)\int_y^x f(t)^2\,dt \leqslant (1-y)\cdot I_2(x)$$
and therefore
$$\frac{I_1(x)^2}{I_2(x)} = \frac{I_1(y)^2 + 2I_1(y)\int_y^x f(t)\,dt + \Bigl(\int_y^x f(t)\,dt\Bigr)^2}{I_2(x)} \leqslant \frac{I_1(y)^2}{I_2(x)} + 2\frac{I_1(y)\sqrt{1-y}}{\sqrt{I_2(x)}} + (1-y)\,,$$
which shows
$$\limsup_{x \nearrow 1} \frac{I_1(x)^2}{I_2(x)} \leqslant 1 - y\,.$$
Since this holds for all $y \in [0,1)$ and the quotient is trivially nonnegative, it follows that
$$\lim_{x \nearrow 1} \frac{I_1(x)^2}{I_2(x)} = 0\,,$$
i.e. $I_1(x)^2 = o(I_2(x))$.